# Backbone, requireJS, Googlemaps - map not displayed

Tags: google-maps, backbone.js, requirejs

I'm having a problem getting a google map to display on my page, I'm using RequireJS & Backbone, and obviously missing something simple (I've only just got started with backbone), but the map never renders on the page. There are no errors and the .map property looks like a google maps object.

Would be really good to get some pointers

The below is as simplified as I can make it, but exhibits the behaviour:

Markup excerpt:

```
<style>
#mapCanvas img { width:auto, max-width: auto; display:inline; }
#mapCanvas {height:600px;}
</style>

<div class="span8">
    <div id="mapCanvas">

    </div>
</div>
```

Code:

```
requirejs.config({
  baseUrl: '../resources/js',
  paths: {
        jquery: 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min',
        jqueryui: 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min',
        datatables: 'http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/jquery.dataTables.min',
        gmaps: 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false',
        backbone : 'libs/backbone.min',
        underscore: 'libs/underscore.min'
    },
  shim: {
    gmaps: {
        deps: ['jquery','async!http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false'],
        exports: 'google'
    },
    underscore: {
        exports: '_'
    },
    backbone: {
        deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
        exports: 'Backbone'
    }
  }
});


 require(["domReady!","jquery","underscore","backbone", "gmaps"], function(doc, $, _, Backbone, google) {

    var siteMarkers = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: "#mapCanvas",
        initialize: function() {

            this.LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(53.785948,-1.40728)
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 8,
                center: this.LatLng,
                mapTypeControl: true,
                mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
                navigationControl: true,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }

            this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.el, myOptions);
            this.render();
        },
        render: function() {
            return this;
        }
    });


     var markerView = new siteMarkers();


 });
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: For what it´s worth I have almost exactly the same setup and it works for me. The only difference is that I don´t shim gmaps but define it before like define 'gmaps', ['async!http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxx&sensor=false'], ->
 google.maps

Comment: Brill, can you put this as an answer so I can accept it please? Works for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of shimming google maps, define it as a module:

```
define('gmaps', ['async!http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxx&sensor=false'], function() {
    return google.maps;
});
```

Comment: @Kyle Are you placing your api key literally where `xxx` is, or are you reading it in from a config file you can hide on github? Thanks!